# How to flush specific user sessions

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a spam checker system in my application. When user made suspicius move, I mark him as "`suspect`" and store this on session.

But in the admin side, I'm checking suspicius moves and if there is no spam attempt I want to remove "`suspect`" mark from this user session

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions are stored in files usually, but you can set it up to database. So if all sessions are stored in the database you can easily update the session from the user directly from your admin account. It s also possible when the sessions are stored in the file but I think it is easier to search when it is in the database.

You can tell laravel where the sessions should be stored, which is shown here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#driver-prerequisites

Comment: I see, but I don't want to communicate with database much, is there way to do that without using database ?

Answer (score 0):

To set session

```
session()->put('session_name',value);
```

To delete session

```
session()->forget('session_name');
```

To delete all session use

```
session()->flush();
```

Comment: I don't wanto delete all session, I just want to delete specific user session

Comment: @HasanTıngır :  you can use this session()->forget('user_session_name');